# Check if string contains integer

Tags: php

I have a value from `$_GET`, and I want it to be integer.

```
$val = "123";

is_integer($val); // false
is_numeric($val); // true
```

How do I check if it's of type int?

Do I really have to use regex, or multiply it by 1 and try is_integer then?

Comment: lol that was fast. It didn't show in the suggested questions though.

Comment: try http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: @RakeshSharma no good, that will give me also floats. but `(string)(int)$val == $val` works good for me.

Comment: [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/ctype_digit)

Comment: giving you true cause Finds whether a variable is a number or a numeric string (so your $val is a string but having numeric chars)

Comment: @deceze `ctype_digit` is useless, I want also negative integer value.